# Asymptotic and left composition

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, asymptotics

Working with asymptotic notation (and Landau symbols) i learned that:

If $f(x)\sim g(x)$ when $x\rightarrow x_0$, then it is **not** necessarily true that
$h(f(x))\sim h(g(x))$ when $x\rightarrow x_0$.

For example: let be $f(x)=x+x^2$ and $g(x) = x^2$, $x_0 = +\infty$. It's true that 
$f(x)\sim g(x)$ when $x\rightarrow x_0$ but if we choose $h(x) = e^x$ we have:
$h(f(x))=e^{x+x^2}$ and $h(g(x))=e^{x^2}$.

We can say with no doubt that $h(f(x))$ it is not asymptotic to $h(g(x))$ because:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}=\dfrac{e^{x+x^2}}{e^{x^2}}=
\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}=\dfrac{e^{x}\cdot e^{x^2}}{e^{x^2}}=
\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}= e^{x}=+\infty
$$

Is there an example as above where $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ and
$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} f(x)$, $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} g(x)$ are both finite ?
My attempts are unsuccesful.

Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=|x|$, $g(x)=-|x|$, $x_0=0$. Let $h(x)=1$ for $x>0$, $h(x)=-1$ for $x<0$.

Comment: Thanks but $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\dfrac{\lvert x \rvert}{-\lvert x \rvert} = -1$. In order to be $f\sim g$ must be $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1$. Is it correct to say that $\lvert x\rvert\sim -\lvert x \rvert$ for $x\rightarrow 0$ ?